# is it possible to put a list directly in a SOQL query?

Tags: soql, query

Is it possible to put a list directly in a SOQL query form the query editor? Let's say I wanted to query over a list, is the following possible in any way?

```
SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName in : ('Johnson', 'Jones') limit 10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. You can do it a couple of different ways.

As here, you can use a literal list, but you wouldn't include a `:` for Apex binding:

```
SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName IN ('Johnson', 'Jones') LIMIT 10
```

Alternately, you can accumulate a `List<String>` or `Set<String>` (since this is a text field) and use Apex binding to reference it:

```
List<String> lastNames = new List<String>{'Johnson', 'Jones'};

List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName IN :lastNames LIMIT 10];
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out but your answer is much more fleshed out! Will mark it as best!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - `SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName in ('Johnson', 'Jones') limit 10`